# How can I strip out "file separator" characters from CSS/text files?

Tags: windows-7-x64, code-cleanup

My CSS files have become contaminated with "file separator" characters (AKA "INFORMATION SEPARATOR FOUR" or ALT/028 characters). How can I get rid of them?

This is the character:
http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1c/index.htm

Background
I manage a number of .CSS text files that are fairly similar. Unfortunately a number of these file have somehow got "file separator" characters pasted into them. Although they do still seem to work in browsers any file that has one of these characters anywhere within it can not be indexed by my desktop search utility (X1 Search). And this is making them extremely hard for me to manage because I need to compare CSS files contantly.

[Bizarrely X1 Search ignores the character if the filename extension is .TXT but files to index the entire file if the filename extension is .CSS]

Worse this "file separator" character is almost invisible within my text editor (TextPad 7.2). The only way I can detect it is to make spaces and carriage returns visible and then it appears as blank space. Worse still it appears to be impossible to search for using text search.

To make it clear what I mean an example that I have pasted into this page. The "file separator" character is on LineB below

LineA
LineB
LineC
LineD

- Is there any way to remove this character from multiple text (in this case CSS) files at once?
  NB I do NOT want to remove the whole line, just the one character(!)
  Thanks

J

P.S. I am running on Windows7 (x64). I am using TextPad 7.3.

Comment: You'll have to tell us which platform you're working on...

Comment: Apologies. OK I have now edited my original question. Windows 7 (x64) and TextPad v7.2.

Answer (score 0):

I have eventually managed to answer my own question.

Text Crawler and the use of a regular expression of "\x1c" appears to be the answer.

Fwiw, both Agent Ransack and FileLocator Pro filter out any characters in the ASCII range 0-31 (excluding 0x09 - tab) from the input field.